# Stop Dialogflow with Facebook Job Application

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es

How can I do a takeover, or pause dialogflow when receiving an attachment via a Facebook Job Application?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS DOES NOT WORK AFTER ALL

---

Ok, figured it out.
Go into the history in Dialogflow and find where someone uploaded an item and copy the url or at least the first part of the url inside messenger.

In this case, a few examples:
--https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/--
--https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/--

Actions and Parameters:
Param name: takeover
entity: sys.any
value: takeover

I also highlighted the training phrases and created sys.url parameters for them and then created another action:
Parameter name: url
entity: sys.url
value: url

Then I added a text response: "Great, we'll be in touch. Thanks."

This is my way of problem solving. I'm not a coder...so totally open for other options, especially if they're easier :)